# Get a line in a file by the use of the specific line number got in a loop

Tags: batch-file

I need to extract a line into a file based on the line number that I got in a loop For. In fact, I get the line 7 from the first FOR command, so far so good and I have to read this line into myfile.txt. The reading operation is performed in the second FOR loop; this step does not work since I get output 'result.txt' empty

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in (lines.txt) do set line=%%a& goto breakFor "%line%"

:breakFor
echo.%line%
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('findstr /n .* "myfile.txt"') do if "%%a"=="%1" set line=%%i
echo.%line%>result.txt
```

Here's a part of myfile.txt and lines.txt

```
lines.txt
7:I=output7
515:I=output515
837:I=output837
851:I=output851

myfile.txt is made of lines of text (I1,I2,I3,...)
I1=some text....
I2=text...
```

Could you please tell me why and help to fix that?
Thanks

Comment: Please post a few lines of the `myfile.txt` and _clearly_ explain what you want to achieve. Don't assume that we know what `line number` means!

Comment: In your example the myfile.txt have 4 lines. The first one have the number 7 before the semicolon. Do you want the line number 7 of this file? But it just have 4 lines!

Comment: I will got the line 7 and search it into myfile.txt to read this line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Batch file below do the following:

- Read the first line of the file lines.txt
- Get the number that appear before a semicolon
- Use this number to locate that line in myfile.txt
- Show that line

.

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in (lines.txt) do set line=%%a& goto breakFor
:breakFor
echo.%line%
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" "myfile.txt" ^| findstr "^%line%:') do set line=%%b
echo.%line%>result.txt
```

Is this what you want? I would prefer do it this way:

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in (lines.txt) do set /A line=%%a-1& goto breakA
:breakA
echo.%line%
for /f "skip=%line% tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" "myfile.txt"') do set line=%%b& goto breakB
:breakB
echo.%line%>result.txt
```

Comment: Not really, result.txt is still empty. Please what do you want to get the number that appear before a semicolon? Indeed I want to get the line 7 into myfile.txt, which is different of lines.txt in which I have retrieved the line number 7. Thanks

Comment: It's okay! Thank you very much. Please could you comment a little your code? What does mean "^" into 'findstr /n "^" "myfile.txt"'? Really Thank you again

Comment: @new: It is entirely equivalent to your `findstr /n .* "myfile.txt"` **;-)** If you think this answer is useful to you, you may upvote it, or accept it as Best answer, or both!

Answer (score 1):

try this and look at the output:

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "line=test"
goto breakFor "%line%"
:breakFor
echo "%~1"
```

Comment: of course. You see: this doesnt work: `for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in (lines.txt) do set line=%%a& goto breakFor "%line%`  and  `if "%%a"=="%1"`.

Comment: Please, Why the example you gave me to test doesn't work?                                                             set "line=test"                                                     goto breakFor "%line%"
:breakFor
echo "%~1"

Comment: your code is corrupt. my example should show, how to make it better.